# how to match "[]" in TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following code in TCL:

```
regexp "\[00]\[00].info.age\\s*=\\s*26" "[00][00].info.age = 26"
```

but it does not match, what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you see my [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18130951/1578604)?

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the second parameter, you should escape the `[` putting the following string, `"\[00]\[00].info.age = 26"`, otherwhise Tcl will perform command execution and return *invalid command name "00"*.

Then, the problem is that you are using quotes `"` for grouping the pattern, but in quotes substitutions happen. Therefore, your *escaped* `[` avoid command execution, but is passed as a simple bracked to the `regexp` command which, in turns, sees it as the beginning of a bracked expression.

You have two choices, the first one is the following

```
regexp "\\\[00]\\\[00].info.age\\s*=\\s*26" "\[00]\[00].info.age = 26"
```

quite ugly but does the job: in the pattern, the first `\\` is substituted by a single `\`, the following `\[` is substituted by a `[` and the pattern becomes this literal string

```
\[00]\[00].info.age\s*=\s*26
```

The other way is to replace the quoting characters in the pattern with the curly braces, to avoid the parser substitution step:

```
regexp {\[00]\[00].info.age\s*=\s*26} "\[00]\[00].info.age = 26"
```

You also have to remove one `\` from each `\\s` because you don't need to escape it anymore.

---

**Edit: a little explaination**

The parser performs substitutions *before* the `regexp` command is executed.

The parser sees the grouping character `"`, so it performs substitutions inside it. Inside `"..."`, a pair of coupled `[...]` are a *command execution*, so the inner command is called and its result replaces the `[...]` string.

To avoid this substitution, you need to escape the `[` using `\[`.

After that, the parser did its job and it's the turn of `regexp`, which is executed.

If the pattern you pass to it contains a `[...]` group, you are giving it a *bracket expression*, that is a set of characters to choose among.

You don't want that, because you must match a *literal* `[`, so you have to tell `regexp` to drop its special meaning: to do that, you have to *escape* it, by placing a backslash `\` in front of it, that is `\[`.

Your code, then, must pass a *backslash* followed by an *opening bracket* to `regexp`, but both are special characters for Tcl too and they have a special meaning to the Tcl parser, which is called first.

So, to remove the special meaning of the *backslash*, the Tcl parser must see *two* backslashes: these are the first two backslashes you see in the pattern, `\\`; to remove the special meaning of the *opening bracket*, the Tcl parser must see it *escaped* by a backslash: this is the third backslash you see in the pattern, `\[`.

I hope this is clearer :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still do not know why we need to put triple \ in front of [, we need to escape [, so \\[, and we need to escape \ in front of \\[, so \\\[, is it not enough?

Comment: No, it's not enough. I added a longer explaination to my answer. Let's see if my words are clearer, now :)

Comment: but why the ] is not need to be escaped?

Comment: Because you already escaped the `[`, so it's not taken as *command substitution* starting sign, and then the `]` doesn't have any special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130951/1578604), use braces and avoid all double escaping:

```
% set str "\[00]\[00].info.age = 26"
[00][00].info.age = 26
% regexp {\[00]\[00].info.age\s*=\s*26} $str
1
```

Otherwise, you'll have to double escape (in this case triple escape? Since `[]` are used to call commands. I'm not sure how to call it...):

```
% set str "\[00]\[00].info.age = 26"
[00][00].info.age = 26
% regexp "\\\[00]\\\[00].info.age\\s*=\\s*26" $str
1
```